# Math journal question - long publishing delay

Tags: publications

My paper was accepted for publication in May 2019. Almost two years later, it still has not been published. Other papers which were submitted and accepted after mine have already been published. What's going on here? Should I email the journal to get an estimate for when my paper will be published? I feel a bit pathetic to have to send them an email to ask "golly gee, when are you going to get around to actually publishing my paper." Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not send a mail to the journal; send it to the editor that handled the paper. They are an academic, so they are going to be more sympathetic and understanding of your deadlines and external constraints. In addition, they have at least some limited power to insist with the production team, and they have a direct interest in their journal's reputation.

And if there is someone that should feel pathetic, I believe, it's whoever receives your e-mail. Two years is really unacceptable even for fields with slow publication times; at least the paper should have appeared as published online (with the word "published" attached to it clearly).